# NodeJs Job scheduler based on selection from calendar

Tags: node.js, scheduler

I am building nodejs app. It is first time I will use job scheduler in my code.

I want a user to select dates and times from calendar (such as bootstrap date time picker) to run a specific script at server at those dates and times. Users chosen schedule will be saved on server and execute the script on server according to schedule.

I searched the net and found some libraries for this such as agenda, later, node-cron, node-schedule etc. And then there a libraries Bull, Bee and Kue.

I am rather lost where to begin. I would very much appreciate if some one experienced in job scheduling in nodejs can guide me concurring to my usage. It would save me lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try date based job scheduling of "node-schedule".
Refer:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#date-based-scheduling

```
var Schedular = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2018, 10, 27, 12, 25, 0);
let nodeScheduler = await Schedular.scheduleJob(date, async function () {
        console.log("Job started.");
        console.log('** do something **');
        console.log(`Job completed`);
    });
```

Where in new Date: 2018- year, 10 - month(0- Jan, 11- Dec), 27 - date, 12 -Hr, 25 - min

Comment: node-schedule looks like easy to start with, but where does it store the schedule, in memory or some database? What will happen to schedule on reboot? Agenda ( https://github.com/agenda/agenda ) uses MongoDB. I think if it saves in Redis, that would be more useful. Can you give me some link where these libraties are compared? Can I use Bull (https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) for my job I mentioned above?

Comment: On restart, the schedule will be lost. For such type, you should go with DB. On restart reconfigure old jobs based on the status of jobs. Yet I have not used Bull so I can't suggest it now.